# Combining Rows into List in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame below with common elements in colomn "id".

```
df<- data.frame(id=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x2"),figure=sample(1:5,6,replace=T))

id  figure
x1  5
x2  5
x3  3
x4  2
x5  5
x2  2
```

I want to combine the rows with the same element as a list in the data frame so it would look something like this

```
id  figure
x1  5
x2  c(2,5)
x3  3
x4  2
x5  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need it to have a nice overview use:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(figure= paste(figure, collapse = " ")), by=id]
```

Which gives you:

```
   id figure
1: x1      4
2: x2    2 2
3: x3      5
4: x4      5
5: x5      1
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is split:

```
split(df$figure,df$id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` way.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x2"),figure=sample(1:5,6,replace=T))

df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(figure = as.character(figure),
     figure = ifelse(length(figure)>=2, 
                      paste(figure, collapse=" "), figure) ) %>%
  unique
```